# GridView never shows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datasource

Using an oracle DB. Can't for the life of me get this grid view to work. I don't know why, but it's making me lose my mind after the last 6 hours of continuous debugging.

My datasource settings are as follows:

```
<asp:sqldatasource runat="server" id="dsSearch"
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OracleConnection %>" 

ProviderName= "<%$ ConnectionStrings:OracleConnection.ProviderName %>" 
CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False" 
SelectCommand="SELECT d.DVD_ID, d.DVD_TITLE, d.RENTAL_COST, r.RATING_NAME, g.GENRE_DESC, d.COVER_IMAGE FROM DVD d, DVD_GENRE t, GENRE g, RATING r WHERE d.DVD_ID = t.DVD_ID AND t.GENRE_ID = g.GENRE_ID AND d.RATING = r.RATING_ID ORDER BY lower(DVD_TITLE)" 
FilterExpression="{1} LIKE '&{0}&'">
<FilterParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="searchBox" DefaultValue=" " PropertyName="Text" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="swapList" DefaultValue="DVD_TITLE" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
</FilterParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

What i'm trying to do is create a search function from the textbox named "SearchBox" and the drop down list of "SwapList". I've added a filter expression (which is the search logic) that looks for the text entered into searchbox and looks for it in the column of whatever swaplist value has been selected.

I understand the problem is potentially with my gridview code so I'll paste below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="sGrid" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsSearch" 
    DataKeyNames="DVD_ID" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DVD_ID" HeaderText="DVD_ID" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="DVD_ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DVD_TITLE" HeaderText="DVD_TITLE" 
            SortExpression="DVD_TITLE" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RENTAL_COST" HeaderText="RENTAL_COST" 
            SortExpression="RENTAL_COST" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RATING_NAME" HeaderText="RATING_NAME" 
            SortExpression="RATING_NAME" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="GENRE_DESC" HeaderText="GENRE_DESC" 
            SortExpression="GENRE_DESC" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="COVER_IMAGE" HeaderText="COVER_IMAGE" 
            SortExpression="COVER_IMAGE" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I've adjusted your tags, this has nothing to do with Oracle directly.

Answer (score 0):

i think your filterexpression should look like this

```
FilterExpression="{1} LIKE '%{0}%'"
```

that is replacing `&` with `%`

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you so much. Shift + 7 is most definitely not the same as Shift + 5 -_-

I'm a fool! Thanks again!